# Is there example of equalizer that is not injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, morphism

we know that in general case every arrow is not function also in the $Div \mathbb{A}b$ there is [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949728/the-category-of-divisible-abelian-groups-pi-mathbbq-rightarrow-frac-mat) of monic that is not injective.

> Is there example of [equalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equaliser_(mathematics)#In_category_theory) that is **not [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)** ?

Comment: Are you asking about the category of divisible abelian groups? Or about a general concrete category (so that "injectivity" makes sense)?

Comment: @AlexKruckman .general concrete category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the category with three objects $A$,  $B$, $C$ and four non-identity arrows, $f\colon A\to B$, $g_1,g_2\colon B\to C$, and $h\colon A\to C$ such that $g_1\circ f= g_2\circ f=h$. Then $f$ is the equalizer of $g_1$ and $g_2$.

Make this category into a concrete category via the functor $F$ to Set sending $A$ to $2$ and $B$ and $C$ to $1$. Then all the non-identity arrows get mapped to the unique arrow to $1$ from their domains. In particular $F(f)$ is the unique arrow $2\to 1$, which is not injective.

Comment: I’m not sure to understand how it works: why would this be an equalizer diagram in set?

Comment: @chaotic It's not an equalizer in Set - I didn't claim this. It's an equalizer in the concrete category I described, whose underlying map of sets is not injective.